# Git - Make all files in a branch dirty

Tags: git, branch, phpstorm

I am using an IDE which allows me to deploy changes to a remote server as part of a commit.
I am trying to find an easy way to deploy to the remote server all the changes I have made on a given feature after multiple commits all in the same branch.
Is there any way to make all files that were modified in a branch "dirty". That way my IDE will now see them as available for a commit and I could do a single commit and push to remote server knowing that every file got to the remote server.

I realize there are better ways to deploy using git but this would be very useful for me for testing an deployment.

Any ideas how to do this? Or if its even possible?

Comment: He specified PhPStorm, which is a Jetbrains IDE like IDEA.

Comment: yep, sorry didnt mention it, thats the one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If dirty means listed in the `git status`, an easy way would be squashed merge with `-n` option. Given `master` and `feature` branches, you could do:

```
git checkout master
git merge --squash -n feature
```

If you have a merge conflict previous line, do `git reset --hard feature` and merge master to it, afterwards repeat from the beginning. At the end you should have all your changes staged and "dirty" in the git's sense.